# How to verifiy JWT on a single route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt

I have a single route in Laravel on which I need to verify the JWT on header if it is authorized and not expired. How can I do that?

In Javascript its really easy, but don`t know how in Laravel.

Here's the code:

```js
public function update(Request $request){

 $header = $request->header('Authorization');
 $token = $request->bearerToken();
 $secret = env('EXAMPLE_SECRETE');

 $verified = here i want to verify the jtw /$token

 if (!verified)
   return 'something here'
 else
    >>code here after verified
}
```

Comment: You can use this package https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of install below package

```
composer require firebase/php-jwt
```

And then you can create a middleware in order to verify Token or expired, below is a complete code of middlware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Exception;
use App\User;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\ExpiredException;

class JwtTokenMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $token = $request->bearerToken();

        if (!$token) {
             // Unauthorized response if token not there\

        }
        try {
            $credentials = JWT::decode($token, env('JWT_SECRET'), ['HS256']);

           //You can get credentials that you have set up while generating token
            $user = User::findOrFail($credentials->sub)->setAuthUser();
            $request->auth = $user;
         } catch (ExpiredException $e) {

            // Token expired response
        } catch (Exception $e) {

           // Handle unknow error while decoding token
            return response()->json([
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```